# Matrix inverse of $ T = \begin{pmatrix} z & A^* \\ A & z \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the block matrix

$$ T = \begin{pmatrix} z & A^* \\ A & z \end{pmatrix}$$
where $z$ is a scalar times the identity on the Hilbert space and $A$ is a bounded operator.

I am wondering if there is a simpler block matrix inversion formula in this special case?

Comment: Are you saying that $A$ is a bounded operator from a Hilbert space to itself, or is it possibly a map to another space?

Comment: no, it maps a Hilbert space to itself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\underbrace{\pmatrix{z & -A^*\\ -A& z}}_S \ \underbrace{\pmatrix{z & A^*\\ A & z}}_T = TS = \pmatrix{z - A^*A & 0\\0 & z - AA^*}.
$$
With this, we can conclude that $T$ has inverse
$$
T^{-1} = \pmatrix{z - A^*A & 0\\0 & z - AA^*}^{-1} \pmatrix{z & -A^*\\-A & z} 
\\= \pmatrix{z(z - A^*A)^{-1} & -(z-A^*A)^{-1}A^*\\
-(z-AA^*)^{-1}A & z(z - AA^*)^{-1}}.
$$
In order to verify that $T^{-1}$ is indeed self-adjoint (for real $z$), note that

$$
(z - AA^*)A = zA - AA^*A = A(z - A^*A) \implies\\
A(z - A^*A)^{-1} = (z - AA^*)^{-1} A.
$$
So, the adjoint of the bottom-left entry satisfies
$$
[-(z - AA^*)^{-1}A]^* = -[A(z - A^*A)^{-1}]^* = -(z - A^*A)^{-1}A^*,
$$
which coincides with the upper-right entry as required.